# how to exit my script with sequence ctrl+c when using timeout

Tags: timeout, sleep

and many thanks by any help.

When I run the command:

```
timeout 10 sh -c 'sleep 6; echo "Done"'
```

in my command line, I am allowed to exit the excecution by the keyboard sequence ctrl+c. However, when I encapsulate the command in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

timeout 10 sh -c 'sleep 6; echo "Done"' 

exit 0
```

the keyboard sequence ctrl+c doesn't have the hoped effect: it is, abort the shell script excecution. In fact, I have to wait 6 seconds and then the shell script fishish.

Could you advice me please to do what I would like to do? To finish the script once the keyboard sequence is given?

Answer (score 2):

The man page for `timeout` specifies the foreground option

```
--foreground
    When  not  running  timeout directly from a shell prompt,  allow  COMMAND 
    to read from the TTY and receive TTY signals.  In this mode, children  of 
    COMMAND will not be timed out.
```